# hashchange polyfill for IE7 that can track more than one event per tick

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to fire a hash change event more than once per tick.

My current polyfill looks like this.

```
//If the hashchange event is missing implement it
hashchangeSupported || (function() {

    //save the current hash for reference next cycle
    var lastHash = location.hash;

    //check the hash for changes every tick
    setInterval(function() {

        //if the hash is different since the last tick then
        // fire a hash change event.
        if(lastHash !== location.hash) {
            trigger('hashchange', window);
            lastHash = location.hash;
        }
    }, 1);
});
```

The problem is that if the hash is updated more than once per tick it still only fires a single hash change event. I'm looking for a way to check for changes more than once per tick.

I know this is asking a lot and I doubt its possible without getters and setters but I'm aware there are better programmers that I on Stack Overflow and I want some second opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible without [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).